# svg fill grouped polylines to make a filled shape

Tags: svg

I working on create an svg floorplan at the momoment, a consists of multiple paths that are grouped together, where there is a break in a path that represents a doorway.

However I try and fill my group I don't get a complete fill, I get fill that is partial and consists of isometric shapes, is there a way to fill a group completely even when I have non joined paths?

My code,

```
<g id="Group" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="blue" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(66.000000, 103.000000)">
    <path d="M184.068359,305.802734 L143.80664,305.802734" id="Path-17" stroke="#979797"></path>
    <polyline id="Path-18" stroke="#979797" points="93.7480469 305.845703 0.466745757 305.845703 0.466745757 92.1182094 141.39461 92.1182094 195.207031 65.8398438 195.207031 54.2361072 188.045332 54.2361072"></polyline>
    <polyline id="Path-19" stroke="#979797" points="188.199219 6.6484375 207.78952 6.6484375 208.511719 0.703125 284.00589 0.703125 284.00589 5.9776195"></polyline>
    <polyline id="Path-20" stroke="#979797" points="284.890625 55.1621094 283.505859 134.390625 183.903627 134.390625 183.903627 306.27391"></polyline>
</g>
```

What I am trying to do is fill everything inside the red strokes as blue, but make it a complete fill?

https://jsbin.com/reyunufeno/edit?html,output

Comment: You'd need to convert things to a single path.

Comment: Sorry, how do you mean?

Comment: Take the polyline elements, convert them to path d values and add that to your existing path's d value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code below I have merged all of your shape elements into one path, beginning each with a new "M" which causes the "pen" to "jump" over the doorways. For the original I coloured the stroke red and made the fill "none". I then just copied that original path and deleted the internal "M"s to "connect" the floor outline across the doorways, eliminated the stroke of the copy and filled the copy with blue.

```html
<svg width="300" height="320">
  <g transform="translate(5,5)">
    <path stroke="red" stroke-width="10" fill="none" d="M184.068359,305.802734 L143.80664,305.802734 M93.7480469 305.845703 0.466745757 305.845703 0.466745757 92.1182094 141.39461 92.1182094 195.207031 65.8398438 195.207031 54.2361072 188.045332 54.2361072 M188.199219 6.6484375 207.78952 6.6484375 208.511719 0.703125 284.00589 0.703125 284.00589 5.9776195 M284.890625 55.1621094 283.505859 134.390625 183.903627 134.390625 183.903627 306.27391"/>
    <path fill="blue"                                d="M184.068359,305.802734 L143.80664,305.802734  93.7480469 305.845703 0.466745757 305.845703 0.466745757 92.1182094 141.39461 92.1182094 195.207031 65.8398438 195.207031 54.2361072 188.045332 54.2361072  188.199219 6.6484375 207.78952 6.6484375 208.511719 0.703125 284.00589 0.703125 284.00589 5.9776195  284.890625 55.1621094 283.505859 134.390625 183.903627 134.390625 183.903627 306.27391"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```